# resume from checkpoint in pytorchlightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am using google colab.
I want to resume from checkpoint file but I've saved only weights.
Error meesage sends me that it only contains weights. How can I convert this file to  file that contains model?

I've loaded this ckpt file and used
torch.save(model,"model.ckpt")
but it does not work.

```
  rank_zero_warn(f"Checkpoint directory {dirpath} exists and is not empty.")
2022-11-12 02:03:37,822 - Restoring states from the checkpoint path at /content/drive/MyDrive/maicon_qualifiers/bit_fold3_cosine_epoch=00048_val_mIoU=0.5898_val_loss=0.0447.ckpt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 38, in <module>
    trainer.fit(model, dm, ckpt_path=opt.resume_from_checkpoint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 583, in fit
    self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 38, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 624, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1005, in _run
    self._restore_modules_and_callbacks(ckpt_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 959, in _restore_modules_and_callbacks
    self._checkpoint_connector.resume_start(checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/checkpoint_connector.py", line 89, in resume_start
    self._loaded_checkpoint = self._load_and_validate_checkpoint(checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/checkpoint_connector.py", line 94, in _load_and_validate_checkpoint
    if any(key in loaded_checkpoint for key in DEPRECATED_CHECKPOINT_KEYS):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/checkpoint_connector.py", line 94, in <genexpr>
    if any(key in loaded_checkpoint for key in DEPRECATED_CHECKPOINT_KEYS):
TypeError: argument of type 'CDBaseModel' is not iterable
```